# Delay the call in catch of promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I have a method in my Db wrapper form nodejs mysql as follow:

```
let mysql=require('mysql')
query(sql,args,count=0){
    let con=mysql.createConnection(configs[this.config])
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        con.query(sql,args,(e,r)=>{
            if(e){

                if(e.code=='ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
                    reject(e)
                }
                r=false
            }
            con.end(e=>{
                return resolve(r)
            })
        })
    }).catch(e=>{
        //want to delay this call
        if(count<5){
            return this.query(sql, args,count+1)
        }
        return false
    })
}
```

In case of failure I am recursively calling `query` but it happens instantaneously. I want to delay this call depending upon `count` which decide the number of retry.

This is how I am using it:

```
let test=async()=>{
    let promises=[]
    for(let i=1;i<100;i++){
        promises.push(db.query('SELECT * FROM verbs'))
    }
    let r=await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log(r[r.length-1],r.length)
}
test();
```

What is some good way to do that? I tried using `setTimeout` but that messed up `promise` chain and I wasn't able to exit in case of success.

Comment: `This is how I am using it` - how is that code even related?

Comment: `.catch(e => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)).then(() => this.query(sql, args, count+1)))` - where `1000` is the delay in ms, change to suit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside catch,

```
let mysql=require('mysql')
query(sql,args,count=0){
    let con=mysql.createConnection(configs[this.config])
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        con.query(sql,args,(e,r)=>{
            if(e){

                if(e.code=='ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
                    reject(e)
                }
                r=false
            }
            con.end(e=>{
                return resolve(r)
            })
        })
    }).catch(e=>{
        //want to delay this call
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                this.query(sql, args,count+1).then(resolve).catch(reject);
            },2000);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Or may be still it is necessary because of `let con=mysql.createConnection(configs[this.config])`. WDYT?

Comment: connection is created and ended every time `query` is called, so I'm not sure it's at all relevant

Comment: What happens if exception thrown at that line.. That is going to throw an uncaught error right.

Comment: will that be caught by a Promise catch?

Comment: if `let con=mysql.createConnection` throws an exception (which is a concern you raised, not me) - then your code will fail regardless of having the `.catch(reject)`  or not - But, if you put `let con=mysql.createConnection(configs[this.config])` **inside** the Promise executor, and it *throws* then the code will handle it OK - i.e. swap lines 3 and 4 - and you really do not need `.catch(reject)`

Comment: I am using this code to wait and retry again in case of there is too many connection. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: If your concern is on creating too many connections, why don't you use a connection pool?

Comment: @ChathuraWidanage Because I am using it with AWS-Lambda and connection pooling does not work properly there. I have tried many alternate and this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: Okay interesting.. I have no idea about your use case. But if there is a possibility, replay failed attempts by coupling lambdas with sqs. Then throttle your lambdas using aws configurations. That will prevent database overloading :) .

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why do you need infinite recursive call during exception. You have to change your design to limit retry.

Anyhow for the above given scenario, Below code can help

```js
let mysql=require('mysql')
query(sql,args,count=0){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let query_data =  () => {
            let con=mysql.createConnection(configs[this.config])
            con.query(sql,args,(e,r)=>{
                if(e){

                    if(e.code=='ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
                        reject(e)
                    }
                    r=false
                }
                con.end(e=>{
                    return resolve(r)
                })
            })            
        }

        try {
            query_data();
        } catch(e) {
            // statements
            console.log(e);
            setTimeout(query_data, 3000);
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: this won't work, because then any call to `query` that has at least one failure will result in `undefined` result rather than the value resolved by `resolve(r)`

Comment: No. it will work. call to query with at least one failure result in retry after 3 seconds.
Please check below executable answer

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it won't work, it can't possibly work

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. catch block must return a promise if I am correct.